# Unhealthy postgres container in docker-compose.yml

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1
    user: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "project"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
```

For some reason I can't run my application due to an unhealthy postgres container. I think this is a permission problem, applicantion runs ok when I remove the "- ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z" line. How can I still persist my data and run?

```
ERROR: for app  Container "47c5271a3e0d" is unhealthy.
```

Comment: Is it important for you to mount the contents of `/var/lib/postgresql/data` on the host machine? The problem in this case is that the folder then no longer has the correct permissions and the initialization script of Postgres is not able to change the permissions.

Comment: Yes it is important. Do you know how I may be able to change the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your host-machine does not have a Linux environment. In this case it is unfortunately not possible to mount a folder from the host-machine into the docker container so that the init script sets the permissions correctly.

But to keep the data persistent there is the possibility to use "named volumes".

For this you have to change the definition like this:

```yaml
postgres:
    ...
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    pgdata:
```

The data will not be visible on your host-machine with this method, but will remain persistent on docker-compose restarts.

Best regards

Comment: @Cesarvspr were you able to persist the data with this proposed solution?

Comment: I think it can solve in some cases. But not mine. The problem is just in the Linux environment, others developers from the project didn't face this. Tks anyway, solved this by commenting.